# Separate "feet / inches" column into two columns

Tags: r

I have the following column from my dataset:

```
HEIGHT
  502
  506
  506
  504
```

The first digit is feet and the last two are inches. How can I split this into two columns? I have tried split(), but it splits up every digit.

```
Feet   Inches   Total_Inches
  5       02         62
  5       06         66
  5       06         66
  5       04         64
```

Comment: Where are there numbers that you don't want to split?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a simple substring would work:

```
df$feet <- as.numeric(substr(df$HEIGHT,1,1))
df$inches <- as.numeric(substr(df$HEIGHT,2,nchar(df$HEIGHT)))
df$total_inches <- df$feet*12 + df$inches

df
#  HEIGHT feet inches total_inches
#1    502    5      2           62
#2    506    5      6           66
#3    506    5      6           66
#4    504    5      4           64
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(HEIGHT = c(502L, 506L, 506L, 504L)), .Names = "HEIGHT", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!